# Microbenchmark: Pass a variable to the function

Tags: r, data-visualization

It was suggested to me to use microbenchmark() instead of system.time() to test the execution times of functions. I'm running in to the problem of being unable to iterate over N values I wish to pass to the function.

```
microbenchmark(function(n), times = 1)
```

I would like to use microbenchmark say for n = 1,2,3....1000 and save the results each time to a list. Is there an easy way to pass an increasing parameter to this function? Loops don't seem to work as the n value doesn't seem to change when passed from outside actual function

```
microbenchmark(list = listoffunctions, times = 1)
```

I did notice you can pass a list to list= and it will do exactly the behavior i wanted. If the list is in the form:

```
alist(function(n1), function(n2),...)
```

Then microbenchmark() will return each one like I am trying to do. I'm not sure how to create an alist, or any other way to create a list of functions that will not actually run the function, but only list it.

I'm hoping to graph the execution times between running a function in several different ways in the end.

Any tips on how to pass a variable to microbenchmark, create a list of functions, or perhaps a better method to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that you are using a *generic* function named `function` and not the R-keyword `function` ...

I think what you're looking for is `call`. I'll start with a function that takes a single argument:

```
myfunc <- function(n) { Sys.sleep(n/1000); return(n); }
myfunc(1000)
# [1] 1000
```

Now we want to know how this function compares with itself given different arguments.

```
lst_o_funcs <- lapply(1:5, function(arg) call("myfunc", arg))
lst_o_funcs
# [[1]]
# myfunc(1L)
# [[2]]
# myfunc(2L)
# [[3]]
# myfunc(3L)
# [[4]]
# myfunc(4L)
# [[5]]
# myfunc(5L)
```

Each of those *looks* like a function call, and per [`call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/call.html),

> `'call' returns an unevaluated function call`

So as you surmised, we can pass that to `microbenchmark`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(list = lst_o_funcs, times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  myfunc(1L) 1.480572 1.487500 1.571667 1.498804 1.505005 1.886452     5
#  myfunc(2L) 2.478316 2.493631 2.592822 2.495090 2.497278 2.999797     5
#  myfunc(3L) 3.484812 3.502680 3.700406 3.507421 3.997177 4.009940     5
#  myfunc(4L) 4.481098 4.481462 4.592104 4.488391 4.499331 5.010237     5
#  myfunc(5L) 5.147718 5.489052 5.432309 5.492335 5.509838 5.522602     5
```

You could name them individually if you really wanted:

```
microbenchmark(list = setNames(lst_o_funcs, as.character(1:5)), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#     1 1.424047 1.455773 1.683110 1.492606 2.004241  2.038885     5
#     2 2.437472 2.492538 5.152970 2.507124 2.507854 15.819861     5
#     3 3.480435 3.488093 3.591150 3.499034 3.500493  3.987695     5
#     4 4.489849 4.520482 5.803837 5.028470 6.227514  8.752872     5
#     5 5.449303 5.501087 5.631566 5.522602 5.565633  6.119206     5
```

though that's for solely cosmestic purposes.

Comment: How to pass to a function with 2 arguments ?

Comment: `Map` is to "n" arguments as `lapply` is to just 1.